# Cron job daily folder report

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, scripts, cron

So I have a script that generates a report about a folder date,folder size, and disk space.

I don't understand how to get the date and time the report was generated and 
My script correctly outputs the result for the rest that i wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For date and time you can make the following changes in your code:
Add this line after `#!/bin/bash`

```
echo $(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

And then your code should look like this:

```
 #!/bin/bash

echo $(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
du -sh /Magna
df -h /Magna
```

Comment: There's really no need to save the output of the `date` command to a variable, and then `echo` it out again